# How do I spread out the tabs in AppBar?

Tags: android

I'm trying to spread out these tabs on my app. I have looked around but I can't find anything about it.

[image: The tabs.]

What I want is Tab1 to be on the left, Tab3 on the way right and Tab2 in the middle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tab1" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tab2" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tab3" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.master.moonbot.MoonBot">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Could you post the layout xml code?

Comment: [Layout XML](https://hastebin.com/zobamumowi.xml) done

Comment: It won't allow me to post it fully, so I have to post in hastebin unfortunately.

Comment: Use a different `app:tabMode`

Comment: Do @cricket_007's suggestion. Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32305076/how-to-fit-the-tab-width-screen-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Support Design TabLayout: Gravity Center and Mode Scrollable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616474/android-support-design-tablayout-gravity-center-and-mode-scrollable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete app:tabMode="scrollable" and it will default to fixed.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
```